# Custom Loss function Keras combining Cross entropy loss and mae loss for Ordinal Classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, loss

I am trying to perform a multi-class classification. Ideally I would use a cross entropy loss to train my neural network. However, my classes are Ordinal variables. Hence, I would what my loss function to enforce some sort of order in the prediction. For example y_true = 2, then I would prefer y_predict = 3 rather than y_predict = 4. For this, I am thinking of using a custom loss function with a combination of Cross entropy loss and mean_absolute_loss after a softmax layer:

```
import from keras import backend as K
from keras import losses
loss_weight = [1,0.0001]
loss_weight_tensor = K.variable(value=loss_weight)

def custom_loss(y_true,y_pred):
   l1 = K.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred)
   y_pred_argmax = K.cast( K.argmax(y_pred,axis=1),dtype=K.tf.float32) 
   # y_pred_argmax get the class from softmax output
   l2 = losses.mean_absolute_error(y_pred_argmax, y_true)
   return l1*loss_weight_tensor[0] + l2*loss_weight_tensor[1]
```

Is there a fallacy in my thinking or construction of this loss function. Does it look like it is a valid loss function (piecewise-differentiable, etc ) given i am using argmax? And do you think tensorflow backend will calculate a valid gradient ? Or are there any better alternative to achieve an ordinal classification?

Comment: You can always try to see if it works. I once worked on an implementation of the negative log-likelihood of the proportional odds model that can be wrapped as a custom Keras loss. The code is [here](https://github.com/sdcubber/f-measure/blob/master/src/classifiers/OR.py), you can always have a look at it. It's not the most effective way of coding this solution, but it works and the notebook contains some references. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea and your code !!